# Cytoscape.js : Stop layout event firing two times?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I initialize my network this way :

```
cytoscape({
    container: container.find('.canvas').get(0),
    ...
    done: function (e) {

        var cy = e.cy;

        cy.add(data);

        var layout = cy.makeLayout({...});

        layout.run();

    },
});
```

And I have listeners on layoutstart and layoutstop events to display/hide some notification message indicating a layout is currently running.

However, when the page is loaded the first time, the layoutstop event seems to be fired two times : one time immediately, one time when the layout actually stops, so my notification message seems to be immediately hidden.

Then if the user re-run a layout through the interface, the events are correctly fired and the notification message is displayed/hidden as expected.

Can someone please explain me whats going on here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cytoscape is doing exactly what you've specified.  You've not set the initialisation layout, and you're calling a layout afterwards.  So the default layout is running and then your layout is running.

Either use the initialisation layout or update your listeners accordingly.

Comment: When Im doing this with arbor layout, startlayout is fired one time then stoplayout three times. I dont understand whats wrong with my code.